# Woocommerce REST API - filtering wp-json/wc/v3/products

Tags: php, json, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

Is there a way - through the functions.php or other - to add custom filters to Woocommerce's wp-json/wc/v3/products endpoint?
First off, **i'm aware you can add parameters to this URL**, however this exact path is accessed by an external tool we use so I have no way to change the URL itself.

I would like to tell WooCommerce that if this exact URL is accessed, some products should not be sent.
Adding additional filters like /categories to the URL sadly is not an option, it needs to be wp-json/wc/v3/products exactly.

Here's what i tried to exclude the product with ID 10522, but it doesn't quite seem to work:

```php
function maximum_api_filter($query_params) {
    $query_params['exclude'][10522];
    return $query_params;
}

add_filter('rest_product_collection_params', 'maximum_api_filter');
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the following code did what i wanted.
It filtered out any products that are priced at 0.00, so anything that costs 0.01 or more is included:

```php
function maximum_api_filter($query_params) {
    $query_params =array("min_price", "0.01");
    return $query_params;
}
add_filter('rest_product_collection_params', 'maximum_api_filter');
```